# How to add large quantities of seconds data to a timestamp in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have some sensor data that is being outputted in an Excel file. Unfortunately, this program produces one timestamp when the test starts and then tracks the progression of the data overtime since that initial timestamp in seconds.

For analytical purposes, I would like to be able to convert all of the time from time in seconds into timestamps to be able to better graph the data.

Here is an example from my data. The output file produces a timestamp when the test starts, which in this case is [2023-04-21  4:03:41 PM] (oddly in my excel I can't format the cell to show yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss, I only have the option to do yyyy-mm-dd h:mm) and in another sheet the "Time" column has the time since the test starts in seconds. I manually added a "Timestamp" column where I hope to add the conversion from seconds to timestamp.

[image] [image]

Here is the equation that I have used to add the seconds to the initial timestamp so far:

**= 2023-04-21  16:03 + TIME(0,0,A2)**

For example, if the test started at [2023-04-21  4:03:41 PM], and one row of data is produced 2500 seconds later, then the new timestamp produced for this row of data is 2023-04-21 16:45.

This is great up until the seconds reaches the number 32767; up until this number, the formula works, after this number, I get a #NUM error. Please see below:

[image] [image]

For this TIME formula, Excel does have this limit:
[image]

Therefore, I'm wondering if there is a formula/method that I can use that will add the time to the timestamp, no matter how many seconds I have (since overtime this number will get very big).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are 86400 seconds in a day, so you can add `#seconds/86400` to the starting time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modular arithmetic to split the increment into hours, minutes, and seconds before passing it to the TIME function. For example, if your increment is in cell A2, you can use:

`= (initial start time) + LET(increment, A2, sec, MOD(increment, 60*60), min, MOD((increment-sec)/60, 60), hour, (increment-min-sec)/(60*60), TIME(hour, min, sec))`

This should be able to add the second-wise increment until the increment reaches 117,961,200 seconds, which is around 3.75 years. Excel does not support that many rows in a single sheet, so you would probably need a different approach by that time anyway.